# Weird auto intent for function below JSDoc

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

When I declare JSDoc right above function inside an object, then reformat the code (`CTRL` + `ALT` + `L`)
the function somehow gets intents.

Before reformat:

```
var SomeClass = module.exports = {

    /**
     *
     */
    execute() {

    }
};
```

After:

```
var SomeClass = module.exports = {

    /**
     *
     */
        execute() {

    }
};
```

I've tired to search for this inside the **Settings** > **Code Style** > **JavaScript** everything seems ok there, (you can actually see an example there in the *Wrapping and braces* tab)

There is a way to prevent this weird intent ?

Comment: This must be a combination of settings (similar kind of things happens with PHP code & PHPDoc in PhpStorm). I may suggest exporting your Code Style and submitting support ticket (with that file attached) to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new . But before that -- try using Default instead of your own code style -- any better?

Comment: looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7543. What WebStorm build do you work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say, this is a bug so now real solution other then waiting for a fix.